# Compiling react-native project in android

Tags: react-native

when I try to compile my project in RN 0.35 using my terminal I receive this error:
What went wrong:

```
Could not list contents of '/MyProject/node_modules/.bin/detect-newline'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

Any help?

**UPDATED**

Seems that the cli.js file was missed in the detect-newline folder.
I created a new project and then I have copied the cli.js file, after that everything worked fine.

Comment: Did you run `react-native link`?

Comment: Yes. Check my updated answer please

Comment: I had this same issue. I resolved it be deleting my node_modules and re-installing